# multi sort list of double lists

Tags: c#, sorting

I have a List of Double Lists,

```
List<List<double>>
```

like this

```
{ 0.0 ,  0.0 , -1.0 , 123.1 , 123.2 , 123.3 }
{ 0.0 ,  40.0 , 1.0 , 123.1 , 123.2 , 123.3 }
{ 1.0 ,  40.0 , 1.0 , 123.1 , 123.2 , 123.3 }
{ 1.0 ,  0.0 , -1.0 , 123.1 , 123.2 , 123.3 }
```

The list needs to be sorted by the first 3 columns; and the sort priority matches the sequence, first column sort, then second then third to provide result below

```
{ 0.0 ,  0.0 , -1.0 , 123.1 , 123.2 , 123.3 }
{ 0.0 ,  40.0 , 1.0 , 123.1 , 123.2 , 123.3 }
{ 1.0 ,  0.0 , -1.0 , 123.1 , 123.2 , 123.3 }
{ 1.0 ,  40.0 , 1.0 , 123.1 , 123.2 , 123.3 }
```

how is this done?
Thx.

Comment: What have you tried doing? So far you are asking us to write code for you, which is not acceptable on SO

Comment: It's really simple - you should just add some code between initial state of list and sorted list

Comment: A list has no columns. Yoou are asking to order a list of lists by the first 3 elements of each list. You should probably be looking for a *different* container. A list of tuples perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `OrderBy()` and `ThenBy()`:

```
List<double> list  = new List<double>() {0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 123.1, 123.2, 123.3};
List<double> list2 = new List<double>() {0.0, 40.0, 1.0, 123.1, 123.2, 123.3};
List<double> list3 = new List<double>() {1.0, 40.0, 1.0, 123.1, 123.2, 123.3};
List<double> list4 = new List<double>() {1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 123.1, 123.2, 123.3};

List<List<double>> lists = new List<List<double>>() {list, list2, list3, list4};

var sortedCollection = lists.OrderBy(i => i[0]).ThenBy(i => i[1]).ThenBy(i => i[2]);
```

You will get collection. If you want to get the list of lists add `ToList()` at the end:

```
var sortedList = lists.OrderBy(i => i[0]).ThenBy(i => i[1]).ThenBy(i => i[2]).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank You that's exactly what I needed.